# Limit numbers of html elements inside one from a dynamic data source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, ecmascript-6

I want to limit to three the numbers of `<Col>` elements inside `<Row>` elements from a dynamic given array.

So for an array of ten elements, I want to render four `<Row>`. The first three with three `<Col>` and the last one with one `<Col>`.

What I am doing now is:

```
const renderElements = elements => {
  let futureRowsIndex = 0;
  const futureRows = [];

  elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (!((index + 1) % 3)) {
      futureRowsIndex += 1;
    }
    if (!futureRows[futureRowsIndex]) {
      futureRows[futureRowsIndex] = `<Col span={8}>${element.name}</Col>`;
    } else {
      futureRows[futureRowsIndex] += `<Col span={8}>${element.name}</Col>`;
    }
  });

  return futureRows.map(futureRow => `<Row>${futureRow}</Row>`);
};
```

And then render it with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

But I don't think that this is the right way to deal with this kind of problem.

So how can it be solved?

Comment: *Note:* SO isn't intended to improve existing working code. That's the general purpose of [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). That said simply _"I think this can be done better"_ is still to broad for that site. You will want to specify why you think your code isn't good. If the problem is you don't think how you render a data-structure is right, you could ask or look for the general best practices for rendering list via HTML. Generally frameworks like react/angular are good for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` and instead, slice data in chunks and map over the sliced data and wrap with `<Col>`s inside of a `<Row>`. Next, push this `<Row>` with `children` into a `chunked` array. After all data has been chunked, React will then render this `chunked` array as a whole.

The `chunked` array will look like this:

```
[
  [
    <Row>
      <Col/>
      <Col/>
      <Col/>
    </Row>
  ],
  [
    <Row>
      <Col/>
      <Col/>
      <Col/>
    </Row>
  ]
  ...etc
]
```

If you want to change the `columns` size, then set a `columns` number that divides 24 evenly (`1,2,3,4,6,8,12`) in `<RenderColors columns={3}/>` located in the **App.js** file!

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/30v7qvoz3m

**components/renderColors.js**

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import React from "react";
import { Col, Row } from "antd";

export default ({ columns, data }) => {
  const chunked = [];
  let key = 0;
  let beginIndex = 0;
  let endIndex = columns;

  while (key <= Math.ceil(data.length / columns)) {
    chunked.push(
      <Row key={key}>
        {map(
          data.slice(beginIndex, endIndex),
          ({ color, background, name }) => (
            <Col
              style={{ background, height: 75 }}
              key={name}
              span={24 / columns}
            >
              <div style={{ color, padding: 20, textTransform: "uppercase" }}>
                {name}
              </div>
            </Col>
          )
        )}
      </Row>
    );
    beginIndex = beginIndex + columns;
    endIndex = endIndex + columns;
    key++;
  }

  return chunked;
};
```

**components/App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import RenderColors from "./renderColors";
import colors from "./colors";

export default () => (
  <div className="container">
    <h1 className="title">Dynamic Rows</h1>
    <RenderColors columns={3} data={colors} />
  </div>
);
```

**components/colors.js**

```
export default [
  { background: "#F44539", name: "Red", color: "white" },
  { background: "#E82363", name: "Pink", color: "white" },
  { background: "#9B2BAF", name: "Purple", color: "white" },
  { background: "#673DB6", name: "Deep Purple", color: "white" },
  { background: "#4152B3", name: "Indigo", color: "white" },
  { background: "#2695F3", name: "Blue", color: "white" },
  { background: "#0BA7F4", name: "Light Blue", color: "white" },
  { background: "#00BBD3", name: "Cyan", color: "white" },
  { background: "#009587", name: "Teal", color: "white" },
  { background: "#4DAE51", name: "Green", color: "white" },
  { background: "#8AC24B", name: "Light Green", color: "black" },
  { background: "#CCDB3C", name: "Lime", color: "black" },
  { background: "#FFEA3D", name: "Yellow", color: "black" },
  { background: "#FFC010", name: "Amber", color: "black" },
  { background: "#FF9700", name: "Orange", color: "black" },
  { background: "#FF5827", name: "Deep Orange", color: "white" },
  { background: "#785649", name: "Brown", color: "white" },
  { background: "#9D9D9D", name: "Warm Grey", color: "black" },
  { background: "#607C8A", name: "Cool Grey", color: "white" }
];
```